# Why is my MVC app throwing a blank page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, deployment

Deploying my ASP.NET MVC 2 application to an IIS7 staging server leads to a blank page, regardless of the action called. Attempts to access controller actions that require authentication are correctly redirected to `/Account/LogOn`, but this page too shows only a blank page on both my local machine and the remote server.

I have checked my site permissions and I think it is an assembly issue, but no errors show up in the Application log.

How do I determine the cause of the error?

I recently installed ASP.NET MVC 3 on my dev machine, but made no changes to this project and I am using StructureMap for DI, if that makes a difference.

Comment: perhaps there is something in the EventLog that indicates what the error might be?

Comment: "no errors show up in the Application log"

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing `Elmah` from Nuget.

In the Package Manager Console, type `install-package elmah`. Then run your app.

Also, if you're not actually getting any errors, have you checked the rendered source in your browser? Your master page could have something commented out in it. Probably not though!

Another suggestion would be to empty the bin directory completely after doing a `Clean Solution`, rebuild, and try again.

In cases like this, it generally helps breaking the problem down to the smallest steps needed to replicate the problem. In your case, remove all routes, barring the one/s you need, empty out your master page and view to just a very simple 'hello world' and also comment out any code in your action so that it's not going off to the database or whatever else.

Comment: I've tried a clean solution and a rebuild, with the same results. I'm now going to try a fresh MVC app to see if it's unrelated to the application.

Comment: Are you using .NET 3.5 or .NET 4? You might want to check that all of the projects and references match the desired runtime, although usually the application would show a YSOD if this wasn't the case.

Comment: .NET 4.0, which is installed on the server with other apps running off it.

Comment: So the Application Pool is set to .NET 4.0 as well? Sounds odd, but I had this situation when it was pointing at .NET 2 by default.

Comment: The application pool is set to 4.0, yes. I'll try compiling for 3.5 and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: A faulty connection string correctly throws a YSOD, indicating that my repository layers is being activated and a fresh MVC app works without problems, so there must be a weird gremlin somewhere in the works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Application_Error handler in the Global.asax, maybe that hides the error.

When I got this problem, there was an error in the web.config